# Unable to create an SSL/TLS secure channel push notification to Firefox, Edge and Safari

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, service-worker

I have a problem when send a push notification to Firefox, Edge and Safari (this works fine at chrome and brave).
**The error returns the value: “Unable to create an SSL/TLS secure channel”**

I think the error is related to the endpoint generated by browsers

This is my code:

Service worker
sw.js

```
self.addEventListener("push", event => {
    let payload = event.data.json();
    console.log(payload);
    console.log(payload.notification.title);
    const options = {
        icon: "/Content/img/icons/icon-192x192.png",
        body: `${payload.notification.body}`
    }
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, options));
});
```

home-ctrl.js

```
const btnsubscribe = document.querySelector("#btn_subscribe");
        btnsubscribe.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(async (result) => {
                if (result == "granted") {
                    VapidKeysDetails.getAllData()
                        .then(async function (result) {
                            if (result.status == 200) {
                                var publicKey = result.data.publicKey;
                                let sw = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
                                const options = {
                                    userVisibleOnly: true,
                                    applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicKey)
                                };
                                sw.pushManager.subscribe(options).then(
                                    (push) => {
                                        const rawKey = push.getKey ? push.getKey('p256dh') : '';
                                        const key = rawKey ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(rawKey))) : '';
                                        const rawAuthSecret = push.getKey ? push.getKey('auth') : '';
                                        const authSecret = rawAuthSecret ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(rawAuthSecret))) : '';
                                        const endpoint = push.endpoint;

                                        vm.webPushNotification.endpoint = endpoint; 
                                        vm.webPushNotification.keysAuth = authSecret;
                                        vm.webPushNotification.keysp256dh = key;
                                        vm.webPushNotification.userId = profile.id;
                                        vm.webPushNotification.groupId = profile.group;

                                        WebPushNotifications.save(vm.webPushNotification)
                                            .then(function (result) {
                                                console.log(result);
                                                if (result.status != 201) {
                                                    //error
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    
                                                }
                                            });
                                    },
                                    (error) => {
                                    },
                                );
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller WebPushNotificationsController.cs

```
[HttpPost, Route("new-user-subscription")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> NewUserSubscription([FromBody] CreateWebPushNotificationsViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            Guid id = default(Guid);
            try
            {
                var dotNetPushSubscription = new PushSubscription(
                  viewModel.Endpoint,
                  viewModel.Keysp256dh,
                  viewModel.KeysAuth
                );

                var vapidDetaildDB = _vapidKeysDetailsReportingRepository.GetAllData();

                var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails();
                vapidDetails.Subject = vapidDetaildDB.Mailto;
                vapidDetails.PublicKey = vapidDetaildDB.PublicKey;
                vapidDetails.PrivateKey = vapidDetaildDB.PrivateKey;
                vapidDetails.Expiration = -1;

                var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
                webPushClient.SetVapidDetails(vapidDetails);

                var userSubscription = _commandRouter.Publish<CreateWebPushNotificationCommand, WebPushNotification>(new CreateWebPushNotificationCommand(dotNetPushSubscription.Endpoint, viewModel.Keysp256dh, viewModel.KeysAuth, viewModel.UserId, viewModel.GroupId));

                var payload = new
                {
                    notification = new
                    {
                        title = "This is a title",
                        body = "This is a message",
                        url = "https://google.com"
                    }
                };

                await webPushClient.SendNotificationAsync(dotNetPushSubscription, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), vapidDetails);

                return Created("Success!", DateTime.Now);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Logger.Error(null, exp);
                return BadRequest(exp.Message);
            } 
        }
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks.